# NodeJS/Express set browser title for PDF return

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

I'm using NodeJS/Express to return a pdf from a HTML file. How can I set the browser title that shows when I send the request.

```
const id = req.params.ID;
const content = await getHtmlData(id) // Here I grab the pdf content

let options = { 
   format: 'letter',
   margin: {
      right: '40px',
      left: '40px'
   } 
};
let file = { content };
html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': pdfBuffer.length
    });
    return res.end(pdfBuffer);
});
```

The router:

```
router.get('/getPDF/:ID', myController.openPDF);
```

It works perfectly, but the browser title shows the ID (the parameter that I sent in the request). How can I change it?

Comment: Please define "browser title"

Comment: @JM-AGMS ```<head><title>Browser Title</title></head>``` Sorry, I think it's the best way to describe it

Comment: Then, I'm assuming you're trying to add a dynamic title to the page, otherwise what you posted would work fine. Use [EJS](https://ejs.co/) to insert dynamic content into a page.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of it?

Comment: [This is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876789/render-html-with-variable-data-and-convert-to-pdf) using a different package, but I'm sure you can make it work with some changes.